# Flutter image upload - Firebase storage errors with FIRStorageErrorDomain : Root certificate is not trusted

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-storage

I'm attempting to upload an image to Firebase Storage, via the iphone simulator within a Flutter application.

My code for the upload is :

```
try {
                  FirebaseStorage _storage = FirebaseStorage.instance;

                  File image =
                      await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
                  String filename = path.basename(image.path);

                  StorageReference reference = _storage.ref().child("images/");

                  StorageUploadTask uploadTask = reference.putFile(
                      image);

                  final StorageTaskSnapshot downloadUrl =
                      (await uploadTask.onComplete);
                  final String url = (await downloadUrl.ref.getDownloadURL());
                  print('URL Is $url');

                  setState(() {
                    _images.add(url);
                  });
                } catch (e) {
                  print("Error received $e");
                }
```

I'm using version

> firebase_storage: ^3.1.3

I'm receiving the following error

```
{
        type = error;
        value = "Root certificate is not trusted.";
    } )
    "LocalDataTask <0EE7042E-6F74-4086-BC11-B6953C86BB09>.<1>" ), _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <0EE7042E-6F74-4086-BC11-B6953C86BB09>.<1>, NSLocalizedDescription=cancelled}
```

I've had a look through and noticed that there was an old bug which seemed similar which has been resolved, however, since I'm using a newer version. I also saw an old Stackoverflow post regarding this and they had suggested to log out and log back in... which I've also done. I'm not sure what this error means and have hit a dead end. What can I do to resolve this ?

I'm receiving the error at

> StorageUploadTask uploadTask = reference.putFile(
>                         image);

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `HttpOverrides` to bypass the certificate issue.

Create a class that extends `HttpOverrides`:

```
class _HttpOverrides extends HttpOverrides {
  @override
  HttpClient createHttpClient(SecurityContext context) {
    final HttpClient client = super.createHttpClient(context);
    client.badCertificateCallback = (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true;
    return client;
  }
}
```

and call the class in main.dart

```
void main() {
    HttpOverrides.global = _HttpOverrides();
    runApp(App());
  }
}
```

reference: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/HttpOverrides-class.html

Answer (score 0):

Use this method to upload image to storage and get download url : -

```
Future<String> _uploadFileToFirebase(String path, File file) async {
   StorageReference reference = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(path);
   StorageUploadTask task = reference.putFile(file);
   return await (await task.onComplete).ref.getDownloadURL();
}
```